# How can I bind many different click functions on one DOM element?

Tags: jquery, events

In my page I define a group of the DOM elements with the same click event (some of them are loaded dynamically)

```
$('div.main-container a.class1, a.class2').live('click',function(){ ... });
```

the element `a.class1` and `a.class2` has their own `click` functions, and in that scenario, my group `click` function does not fire. So, is it possible to bind two different `click` functions to the one DOM element ?

Comment: Why don't you just put two functions in the one click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine all the relevant handlers you need in a function and bind all the click events to something like this:

```
function ()
{
    handler1();
    handler2();
    handler3();
}
```

Cheers